How to make the /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern file writeable in docker containers/
Our application is crashing in the cluster i.e containers and the core dump files need to be taken out of the container before it restarts.
We have taken the approach of mounting the path using the persistentVolumeClaims and the persistentVolume via the helm charts.
Now the problem we are facing is the
/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern is read-only in the containers and it has content as
|/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %p %u %t %h
When the application crashes, we are not sure where the core dump is getting generated.
Is there a way to make the file writeable or change its content in the clusters?
Note:

In the containers, i am not a root user.


If that's not one of the namespaced sysctls, then you can't set it at the container level.  Containers usually don't (and really shouldn't) run systemd, so trying to pipe a core dump through a systemd helper might just not work at all.

Is there a way to disable the systemd in the docker file itself as we do not have permission to run the systemd inside the containers.

Explanation of core pattern: man page.
Your core files are being piped to systemd-coredump. If you don't have that binary inside docker, they are probably going nowhere.
core_pattern is a kernel configuration variable and docker shares the kernel with the host, you can't have a different value inside docker.
You can either provide a systemd-coredump binary inside docker that does something well-defined (e.g. a shell script that cats the contents of stdin somewhere). Or you could change your core_pattern to something that is a writable location in both the host system and docker.

Systems-coredump binary is present inside the containers. I guess it will create core dumps files at /var/lib/systemd/coredumps.  The problem we are facing is we are not able to locate the core dump file in the containers. We are guessing that the core dump file is written to the host file system. Is there a way to change the corepattern content just to reflect only inside this container? Should we mount the host path from the host machine so that the core dumps become visible inside the containers

@Napster92 your options are: make the location writable (shared?), change systemd-coredump to something else inside docker, or patch the kernel if you feel really adventurous... (Note: linked thread also explains why it might not be the best idea)

Patch the kernel is not an option for us.
change systemd-coredump to something else inside docker: how to do this?
